# Android: Updating foreground service sometimes result in showing notification even when Foreground Service is killed

Tags: android, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I have a foreground service with close button in the notification which killed the service. When service start & user immediately (within a second) trying to shutdown the service by clicking on close button on notification. When i am updating this foreground service notification based on Rest Api call response. In this scenario its a close call when user click on close & api response recieved at same time the update notification code is executing.The notification is still shown to user after Api response processing. Even i put a check whether foreground service is running or not but it still updating the notification making user believe that this foreground service is not stopped.

below is code fore creating forground service :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    String title = "Creating ...";
    intent.putExtra(TASK_ID, -1);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = myNotificationUtil.getBuilder(title, "Calling" + " ..");
    mBuilder.setUsesChronometer(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    stopIntent.setAction(MyIntent.STOP_FOREGROUND);
    PendingIntent stopPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, 0);
    mBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_call_end_white_24dp, "Hang Up", stopPlayIntent);
    startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
```

below is update notification method :

```
   private void updateForeGroundNotification(String status) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        String title = "Updating ...";
        
        intent.putExtra(TASK_ID, task_id);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = myNotificationUtil.getBuilder(title, status + " ..");
        mBuilder.setUsesChronometer(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        stopIntent.setAction(MyIntent.STOP_FOREGROUND);
        PendingIntent stopPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, 0);
        mBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_call_end_white_24dp, "Hang Up", stopPlayIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

I have to just update the title of notification after api call in the Notification

Comment: Why don't you try to update title after response receive ?

Comment: I did that but what is actually happening if service dies it shows a normal notification which can be dismissed also